# momentary voltage dropout

Tags: voltage

I have a phone answering machine which drops out on the frequent momentary power interruptions we experience in florida. It has an 11 volt 350 ma supply. all I want is something to momentarily bridge the dropout. not something  like an ups. any ideas?

Comment: How long is "momentary"?

Comment: Large enough capacitor on supply. If necessary - higher voltage supply with large cap on that followed by a voltage regulator - gives greater allowed voltage dip. Andy's battery can be good but must be floated at 13.7V or will die sooner than later.

Comment: You might check with the manufacturer if they make a battery backup unit. I had Panasonic wireless phones that had such a unit. Basically it had 9v (6 AA batteries) connected inline with the power adapter. The 9v would switch in when the AC dropped out.

Answer (score 1):

Power it from a 12V battery and use a charger to keep the 12V battery topped-up. If the 11V is critical then a low-drop-out voltage regulator can be employed to reduce the 12V to 11 volt.

[Here's](http://www.rapidonline.com/Electrical-Power/Yuasa-Yucel-Y1-2-12-Valve-Regulated-Sealed-Lead-Acid-SLA-Battery-12V-1-2Ah-18-5212) a likely choice: -

[image]

It's 97mm x 43mm x 58mm and is 1.2 Ah rated.

Comment: FWIW battery as suggested can be good but must be floated at 13.7V or will die sooner than later. Floating at 12V is reasonably rapidly fatal. So this may need a separate charger for the battery  - or feed answerphone from battery via 2 diodes and from battery charger via diode so that charger usually 'wins'. (Or some such depending on exact charger cct.)